# Unable to understand the HLDA Output in MALLET

Tags: java, mallet

Below is a snippet of my code:

```
HierarchicalLDA hlda = new HierarchicalLDA();
hlda.initialize(instances, instances, 5, new Randoms());
hlda.estimate(1000);
hlda.printState(new PrintWriter(new File("Data.txt")));
```

I am unable to understand the meaning of both the console output and what is printed in the "Data.txt" file. I have already scoured the MALLET site but haven't found anything helpful. Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In hLDA each document samples a path through a tree of topics. Each token exists on one "level" of that path. The `printState` method gives you the ids of each tree node in the path for the document, followed by information about the word: the numeric ID for the word, the string for that id, and the level in the path.

```
    node = documentLeaves[doc];
    for (level = numLevels - 1; level >= 0; level--) {
        path.append(node.nodeID + " ");
        node = node.parent;
    }

    for (token = 0; token < seqLen; token++) {
        type = fs.getIndexAtPosition(token);
        level = docLevels[token];

        // The "" just tells java we're not trying to add a string and an int
        out.println(path + "" + type + " " + alphabet.lookupObject(type) + " " + level + " ");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Professor! The output makes a lot of sense to me now. I was wondering how can I identify the hierarchy of the topics from this output though, and also the words which belong to each of those topics.

Comment: 1. So does each path represent a single document? Also, when I ran the hlda on 10 documents, in the output state file I could see only 5 paths (4 distinct ones and 1 got repeated in the end) with all the words at different levels. 2. In my case, did the 10 documents share the 5 paths. If so, how do I know which documents sampled which paths?